# How to know which axis to do operation along an axis in numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been working with `numpy` and `pandas` for a long time but I'm still usually confused by the concept of doing an operation along an axis.

For example, if I have a data of shape [200,5], and I want to find the mean with the resulting shape [1,5], I would first call `data.mean(axis=0)`, and if it doesn't work, I would try `data.mean(axis=1)`.

Turns out, `axis=0` is correct in this case. But I don't have good terminology for me to remember which axis to use.

Currently, I think that whatever axis I want to reduce the shape to 1, I will need to apply the operation on that axis.
This works fine for Reduction operation like `mean`, `sum` or `std`.

But I don't know how to think when I would like to apply operations that do not reduce the shape like `divide`, `add`, `sort`, etc. (For `divide` and `add` of different shapes, broadcasting is involved)

So it made me curious about how the guy who created `pandas` and `numpy` think intuitively about this. It made curious about what they exactly mean when they say "sorting along the row axis".

I want to understand it so clear that I know what results I'm going to expect when I call a certain axis!

Comment: You're better off searching for information on google yourself than hoping someone will rehash what has already been said countless times by now.

Comment: In a 2d array this can be confusing (even for me).  But it is clearer if I look at a 1d - the sum applies to that one axis.  Or a 3d where the sum applies to one, but leaves the other two.  But as you say it's more obvious when dealing with reduce operations.

Comment: I've tried searching of course. When I don't find it, so I asked. What is so wrong about asking stuff?

Comment: And the thread that you attached is similar to mine. But I haven't found it with my wording when I searched Google. And most importantly, it's not about operations that do not reduce the shape. So it does not apply for me. I already know most of the stuff they said there.

Comment: Confusion like this is why I keep a Ipython session open - to test code snippets.  I'm not particularly happy with the duplicate.  It goes into a lot of detail, where as I think the OP wants a more intuitive answer.